# X and Y are two dependant random variables. Find the distribution of C if C = Y-X

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

> There are 20 balls in a bag and 7 of them are red. If you pick a red ball, you take it out from the bag. Otherwise, you put it back in.
>
> Let X: The number of red balls you pick after 2 tries
>
> Let Y: The number of red balls you pick after 3 tries
>
> Question: Let C = Y-X, calculate the distribution of C.

I start by finding the distribution of X and Y with the help of a tree diagram:

[image]

Then, I believe I need to make a joint distribution of X and Y:
It took me a while to figure it, but here it is:[image]

I know that X and Y are mutually exclusive for sure too. 
But now I'm stuck because I don't know what to do with it. I have absolutely no idea how to find the distribution of C.

I need to fill the distribution for C, if C = Y-X:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.. Thank you.

Comment: Let R stay for a red ball, 0 for an other color. Which are the values of $X,Y$ in each of the following cases $ABC$, where $A$ is the first extracted ball, $B$ the second one, $C$ the third one: $ABC$ runs in the list 000, 00R, 0R0, 0RR, R00, R0R, RR0, RRR? Try to draw a tree and get the probability of each "path" $ABC$.

Comment: I already did that (final answer marked as a) and b). I need help on the final question "Let C = Y-X, calculate the distribution of C".

Comment: The joint distribution table you have shown is not correct. You have forgotten that the random variable Y can also take the value $3$. Once you have found the true joint distribution, then you can begin finding the distribution of $C$ which will range from $-2$ to $3$; however some of these values very well could have a probability of $0$. For example, probability that $C=3$ is actually $0$ because how can we have 3 red balls after the third draw if we had 0 red balls after the second draw? I haven't calculated it myself yet, but I bet that $C$ can only be either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing out a typo! (Third column is not Y, it's 3). But you are correct, they are worth 0 except for $0$ and $1$. Thanks all!

Comment: Ah, I see now, I saw the Y and didn't see that it was merely a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Assuming your joint distribution is correct ...) Each cell in the table of the joint distribution gives a value of $p(x,y)=P(X=x,Y=y).$ Now $C=Y-X$, so for each $c$, $p(c)=P(C=c)=P(Y-X=c)$ is just the sum of all those cells that have $y-x=c:$

[image]